# White thick border on profile image while trying to wear hats

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

The title pretty much says it all, and here is the screenshot:

[image]

Why is there the white border on the hats tab? It kind of looks weird.

The fix: Just get rid of the white border.

Also, it doesn't limit the hat inside the white border boundary, my hat can go outside of it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not the one who originally designed it that way, but for this year's Winter/Summer Bash, I decided to keep it in for this reason:

- **It tells the user that hats can be worn out of bounds.** If a user worries the hat might get cut after placing it, this white "canvas" help communicate it won't.

As to why hats can still be placed outside of this canvas: Think of it as a safe zone which if you place it correctly inside of the white space, it won't obstruct the interface (see image below). We allow to go even beyond because it's fun to break rules. And Winter/Summer Bash is fun.

It wasn't for aesthetic reasons.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The use of a surrounding frame is correct from a design and artistic point of view, it's usually called a [*passe-partout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_(picture_framing)) and is widely used.

I also noticed the frame in the hat choice dialogue and I thought its use made the design better than just framing the avatar as is.